# Linux computer Screen frozen

Tags: linux, freeze

I have a dual booted laptop, Windows+Linux. For a number of reasons, I ended up not using Linux for over a week. When I finally opened it today, my screen has frozen. Before that, it never had hanging issues (my Windows side tends to hang a lot though for the first few days after not being used for a long time)

The cursor moves as I move my mouse/rub my mousepad, and hover effects also work, but I cannot click on anything. So I cannot open my konsole and type kill commands I found on the net.

I have restarted the computer (using the power button) thrice already, but same result.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Edit: ISSUE RESOLVED
I had to leave my laptop unattended for a number of hours, and when I came back it was working normally

Answer (score 0):

What linux distro and version?

Maybe you have Gnome then switch to a virtual terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in, then:

```
sudo killall -9 gnome-shell
```

It's possible that this is another or similar problem.

Comment: I did try that and it didnt work. Anyway, the issue is resolved now, thanks for your time.